# How to make status bar white or hide?

Tags: android, xml, themes, statusbar

Here is top of my launcher theme:

[image]

But why my status bar is black?
Here is the code:

```
<style name="LauncherScreenTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Set visibilty to gone.

Comment: @PrajwalW it s not my element. It s top element where u can see time wifi etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to add white color to the Status bar:

```
 <item name="android:statusBarColor">#FFFFFF</item>
```

Also you can use:

```
 <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

To make a lighter status bar color as per your need.

Update:

Try setting the parent theme to a lighter version. Like)

```
   parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

> Updated Ans: as none of them worked!
>
> Inside of your colors.xml file present under values folder,  Replace
>   the colorPrimaryDark color with the color that you need to set for
>   your Status Bar like:

```
 <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#8e0038</color> //your color code.
```

***Android OS uses the Dark color specified in your colors.xml to set the color to the Status Bar in your app.***

Comment: yep, 2 minute ago, and transparent and white color. Status bar is black...

Comment: Instead of parent DayNight try using some other theme. Check the updated ans.

Comment: I need DayNight theme in my application.

Comment: When u used the other Light theme, did that fixed the issue?